# Python : Why the name of the function is automaticly add at the end?

Tags: python, function

Here is the code I am working on:

```
def ligneComplete(x,y): #function to print a full line of #
   for loop in range(y):
      print(x, end = "")
   return ligneComplete

def ligneEspace(x,y,z): #function to print a ligne of # with space between
   for loop in range(z-2):
      print(x, end="")
      for loop in range(y-2):
         print(" ", end="")
      print(x)
   return ligneEspace 


x = "#"
z = int(input()) #nbcolonne
y = int(input()) #nbligne

print(ligneComplete(x,y)) #print a full ligne of #
print(ligneEspace(x,y,z)) #print ligne with space

#why there is a break line here???????

print(ligneComplete(x,y)) #print full ligne of #
print()
```

And here is the result:

```
#####
#   #
#   #
#   #

#####
```

I would like this:

```
#####
#   #
#   #
#   #
#####
```

Can someone tell me why there is a break line at the end of my function? I tried to find some answers but every topic is about adding a line break not delete one.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your code is outputting `###<function ligneComplete at 0x7f46ab110840>
# #
<function ligneEspace at 0x7f46ab110b70>
###<function ligneComplete at 0x7f46ab110840>` for me.. fix your code

Comment: After printing from within the functions, you're returning them as well Any reason for that?

Comment: Do not nest a for loop inside another one using same loopvar name. This leads to confusions. Also, the last print in `ligneEspace` hasn't `end=''`

Comment: your code is messed up. if you are calling `print` from the function themselves, then there is no need to call `print` again. Simply call those functions. Also, as is already pointed out, there is no need to return the functions

Comment: What AK47 said. It's not possible for the code you show to print that output.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few mistakes in your code:

- You don't need to return anything from these functions.
- You don't need to call print on these functions.
- You don't need explicit loop variables in these cases.
- There is a missing `print()` in the first function.
- As AK47 said, what you claim is the actual output is not what I saw.

Your functions should be like this:

```
def ligneComplete(x,y): #function to print a full line of #
   for _ in range(y):
      print(x, end = "")
   print()

def ligneEspace(x,y,z): #function to print a ligne of # with space between
   for _ in range(z-2):
      print(x, end="")
      for _ in range(y-2):
         print(" ", end="")
      print(x)


x = "#"
z = 5 #int(input()) #nbcolonne
y = 5 #int(input()) #nbligne

ligneComplete(x,y) #print a full ligne of #
ligneEspace(x,y,z) #print ligne with space
ligneComplete(x,y) #print full ligne of #
```

Output:

```
#####
#   #
#   #
#   #
#####
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you don't want to be printing the functions as you call them. The functions call print() themselves.

```
ligneComplete(x,y) #print a full ligne of #
ligneEspace(x,y,z) #print ligne with space

#why there is a break line here???????

ligneComplete(x,y) #print full ligne of #
print()
```

Comment: While this is a step in the right direction, it's not an actual solution to the problem because the output is still messed up

Answer (score 0):

```
def ligneComplete(x,y): #function to print a full line of #
   for loop in range(y):
      print(x, end = "")

def ligneEspace(x,y,z): #function to print a ligne of # with space between
   for loop in range(z-2):
      print(x, end="")
      for loop in range(y-2):
         print(" ", end="")
      print(x, end='')


x = "#"
z = int(input()) #nbcolonne
y = int(input()) #nbligne

ligneComplete(x,y) #print a full ligne of #
ligneEspace(x,y,z) #print ligne with space

ligneComplete(x,y) #print full ligne of #

print()
```

will work.